# How to use ffmpeg to decrease video file size drastically

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

I've looked around, but all I can find is people asking how to decrease file size *without* losing quality. I don't care about quality, I just want to get the smallest file size I can. I'd prefer to have it still be (vaguely) watchable, and I'd like to keep the audio relatively ungarbled, but I don't care if the video is 64x64, 10fps, 1kb bitrate. I just want it small.

Edit: I should clarify that the original video file is >1 hour long. I'm looking for any way to *quickly* convert it, since everything I've tried so far has been pretty slow.

Comment: literally just fill in those parameters to the ffmpeg commands [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: If it doesn't need to be watchable, not sure what the point of having it is, exactly.

Comment: Better create a blank file with the same name. Can take as much as 0 bytes. Quick conversion not only depends on the codec you use and the settings, but also on the power of your computer.

Comment: Stack has [a useful recent answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38380/345853)

Comment: Try the following which was only *just* watchable on my system: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -crf 40 -c:a aac -b:a 32k output.mp4`. crf can go to 63 but this produced only moving pixels on my system, audio at 32k was just able to be followed. Better options can be given if you reveal details of the original file by running: `ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by the amazing [andrew.46](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406193/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-decrease-video-file-size-drastically?noredirect=1#comment2442912_1406193):

> Try the following which was only just watchable on my system: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -crf 40 -c:a aac -b:a 32k output.mp4`. crf can go to 63 but this produced only moving pixels on my system, audio at 32k was just able to be followed.

I slightly modified the command to add `-vf "scale=128:72, fps=10"`, just to scale down the output and reduce the framerate.

Comment: Looks good! It is a pedantic point but h.264 prefers height and width to be divisible by 2. *Easiest* way to guarantee this and also maintain aspect ratio is to use: `-vf scale=128:-2` in your example. The syntax you have given in your answer is of course fine but this is a useful trick and FFmpeg does all the complicated aspect ratio calculation for you...